# How can I make the last two images line up two by two on the last row when resized?

Tags: html, css

When the screen resolution hits tablet size, my images line up two by two except for the last two - they are piled on top of one another. Any idea how to make them line up next to each other as the rest?

I've been trying all morning and can't seem to get it right. I'm sure it's a simple thing.

```css
.meettheteam { text-align: center; background-color: #f2707e; }
  .banner { text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; padding-top: 2%; }
  
  .mtt { display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
  
  .mtt2 { display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
  
  .mtt3 { display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
  
  #one { padding-right: 20px; }
  #two { padding-right: 20px; }
  #three { padding-right: 20px; }
  #four { padding-right: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="meettheteam">
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576445849f74567f15556571/1466189188385/STL-Meettheteam-Mobile.png" alt="meet the team banner">
  </div>

  <div class="mtt">
    <img id="one" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Name</figcaption> 
    <img id="two" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
</div>

  <div class="mtt2">
    <img id="three"
 src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    <img id="four" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mtt3">
    <img id="five" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    <img id="six" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't `#five` and `#six` have the padding that the others do?

Comment: Any reason why all your CSS class selector rules seem to be the same? Same question for the ID selectors.

Comment: Paulie_D, I just edited it in my code to apply to #three and #four and gave it padding left and right. I just needed padding between the images.

Comment: Because they are similar objects that I'm targeting, I'm just keeping them separate. Maybe I don't need to have an ID for each individual picture? Still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use flexbox in these situations (see snippet below) :

```css
.meettheteam { text-align: center; background-color: #f2707e; }
  .banner { text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; padding-top: 2%; }
  
  .mtt, .mtt2, .mtt3 { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="meettheteam">
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576445849f74567f15556571/1466189188385/STL-Meettheteam-Mobile.png" alt="meet the team banner">
  </div>

  <div class="mtt">
    <div>
      <img id="one" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="two" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </div>
</div>

  <div class="mtt2">
    <div>
      <img id="three"
 src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="four" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mtt3">
    <div>
      <img id="five" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="six" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576436f4579fb3558d9753f3/1466185460557/STL-Team-Desktop.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

As others suggested, you don't have the same rules on the last images so it's more likely the source of the problem...
By the way, why would you bother repeating the same rules again ? For example, you have this :

```
.mtt { display: flex; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }

.mtt2 { display: flex; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }

.mtt3 { display: flex; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
```

which is the same as this :

```
.mtt, .mtt2, .mtt3 { display: flex; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; max-width 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
```

Or the images that can be targeted with :

```
div:not(.banner) img { padding-right: 20px; }
```

Comment: flex box is fine for the tablet size, but when I change to flex, it makes my desktop version look pretty unappealing. I don't have much experiences with using flex - I need to read into it more.

Comment: add justify-content: space-between (try the above snippet in full page mode). You can do a lot of things with flexbox to change the positions of the images (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)